# An error occur When i try to build android app

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, ionic4

I got this error when i try to build android app

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

My top-level file:

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
       google() 
       jcenter() 
    } 
    dependencies { 
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0' 
    } 
}

allprojects { 
    repositories { 
       google() 
       jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: show your gradle file ,replace compile with implementation and api accordingly

Answer (score 0):

"Compile" Scope for the dependencies are being taken away from Android development, so instead use "Implementation" as a scope for all the dependencies. You can change it by right click on the folder (e.g. App) then "module setting>dependencies>scope" and then sync the project.

Answer (score 0):

> There is many solution according to [github issues](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking-attribution/issues/555)

first remember android have removed `Compile` Scope for the dependencies new  `Implementation`

one way

right click `App` then

`module setting--->dependencies---->scope` and then sync your project

Other way

upgrade `classpath com.google.gms:google-services` to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' in file in `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    }
    dependencies {
          classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'<-------*****
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

Comment: my code in build.gradle .. even i added 'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'' no issue fixed

Comment: i tried to build android apk file in ionic 4 i got this issue

Comment: seach `Compile` and replace `Implementation` to it

Comment: still it shows 'Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html'

Comment: @GG19CURI post also your module/build.gradle file pls